# There is no way to include an embedd code to hide components

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to hide those elements that are highlighted in yellow using the embed code?

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 0; overflow: hidden; padding-bottom: 56.25%; border-style: none;"><iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/LeYsRMZFUq0?vq=hd1080&amp;autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;cc_load_policy=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;controls=0&amp;disablekb=1"></iframe></div>
```

[image]